# Redirect request not specifying API version to the default version

Tags: nestjs

We define versioning like this:

```
  app.enableVersioning({
    type: VersioningType.URI,
    defaultVersion: "1"
  });
```

It adds gloable prefix `v${version}` to routes, and is configurable. So client must send request like this `api/v1/users`. What I want is to not send `v1` from the client for most requests and make nest automatically redirect from `api/users` to `api/v${defaultApiVersion}/users`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can use `VERSION_NEUTRAL` to mark default endpoint version :

> Some controllers or routes may not care about the version and would
> have the same functionality regardless of the version. To accommodate
> this, the version can be set to VERSION_NEUTRAL symbol.
>
> An incoming request will be mapped to a VERSION_NEUTRAL controller or
> route regardless of the version sent in the request in addition to if
> the request does not contain a version at all.

So, for example, here, route with `v1` or `without version` will both be processed by `getMessageV1` :

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Version(['1', VERSION_NEUTRAL])
  @Get()
  getMessageV1(): string {
    return 'Message V1';
  }

  @Version('2')
  @Get()
  getMessageV2(): string {
    return 'Message V2';
  }
}
```

More details on [official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning#version-neutral).